# How to create URL for webhook receiver within the script?

Tags: python, webhooks

I need to connect to a webhook to retrieve data every-time a survey is taken. The tool I am using requires me too pass in a call back url.

Is there anyway I can generate a static URL within my script that can act as my call back url?

I found this receiver script online but this only listens to port 8080:

```
import web

urls = ('/.*', 'hooks')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hooks:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.data()
        print
        print 'DATA RECEIVED:'
        print data
        print
        return 'OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80)` would run it on port 80 and allow external connections... which is the normal html port (80) ... you would then need to get your IP address from something like whatismyip.org ... you could then connect `http://my.ip.address` ... except that you probably have a router that will intercept the incomming request... you can set up a forwarding rule directly on the router (ie redirect all requests on port 80 to your local ip (ie `192.168.1.12` or something like that anyway)) ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley would you method work on say a AWS box?

Comment: of coarse ... but you need to setup a public IP and setup routing rules to allow it... although i think you could just use their lambda stuff

Comment: @JoranBeasley would you strategy work with AWS?